# ООП вопрос, метод Main в Java или C# !

Tags: ооп

Добрый день ! Подскажите мне, вот допустим есть программа у неё несколько классов (к примеру пять) в классах есть методы и разные поля и что бы всем этим пользоваться я всегда обязан создавать обьект этих классов в методе Main, а так же использовать весь функционал данных классов можно только через метод Main ? Спасибо ...

Comment: Вы можете, например, вызвать из `Main` другие статические методы разных классов. Или создать _один_ объект, вызвать его публичный метод, который запустит программную логику. Возможностей море.

Comment: @Paveladro простите, а как вы пришли к такому странному выводу?

Comment: Читаю Троелсена, там примеры программ такие: допустим три класса с функционалом, а обьекты этих классов и вызов функций всё описано в методе Main !

Comment: Видимо, вы очень невнимательно читаете Троелсена.

Answer (score 5):

Метод main это просто точка входа в вашу программу. Нет нужды всю логику работы описывать только в нем.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вопрос можно разбить на несколько.

#### Всё ли в приложении нужно делать через метод main(String[] args)?

Нет, как выше правильно ответили, это просто точка входа в программу. Вы можете из нее вызывать методы других классов, и управление таким образом перейдет к ним.

#### Всегда ли нужно создавать объект класса, чтобы использовать его методы?

Нет. Есть статические поля и методы - они относятся к самому классу и обозначаются ключевым словом static. Они вызываются не на объекте, а на самом классе:

```
MyClass.foo()
```

Однако для методов без `static` нужно создавать экземпляр.

#### Откуда можно использовать функционал объектов класса. Только из метода, где они созданы?

Если передать ссылку в другой метод, то можно использовать и из него.